# How Can I Start Chose What to do If User Chose On Option From Inline Keyboard In Telegram Python Bot API

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

)

I'm writing a test bot with python-telegram-bot API and This is My Code below

I have a loop and a nested dictionary and loop go through dictionary and read all questions

Now I want to send each question to user and get the answers and save all answers in a list and then calculate the result

My Problem is at this point that i Can't get options from user and then try to decide what to do per options.

For example here i want if user select "MBTI TEST" then go to loop and start asking Questions

and My other question is My Question Function get 4 parameters (bot,update,x,y) that bot and update is default and x and y is a counter parameters that i send to function to find what question is it.

In usual when function just have (bot,update) parameters there is no need to write these parameters and we can just write function name.like start function that when we define we write def start (bot,update) : and when we call we just write start
how can i send x and y parameter to function?

```
import telegram
import telegram.ext
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *

TOKEN = ''
updater = Updater(TOKEN)
question_E={0:'خود مردم برای من جذاب ترند تا عقاید و احساسات آنها',1:'با 
دیگران بودن به من انرژی می دهد',
        2:'ارتباط برقرار کردن با دیگران را دوست دارم',3:'در مقایسه با 
اطرافيانم دوستان و آشنایان زیادی دارم',
        4:'خودم را اجتماعی ميدانم',5:'ممکن است بعضی ها مرا نادان و سطحی 
پندارند',6:'شناختن من آسان است'}
question_I={0:'معتقدم که شناختن من دشوار است',1:'من آدم نسبتاً عميقی 
هستم',2:'دوست دارم با خودم خلوت کنم و درباره زندگی فکر کنم',
    3:'دوست دارم فقط با عده کمی دوست باشم اما صميمی و نزدیک',4:'با مردم 
بودن مرا خسته می کند',
    5:'خيلی وقتها دوست دارم با خودم تنها باشم',6:'ترجيح می دهم با ایده 
ها و احساسات سر و کار داشته باشم'}
question_S={0:'دوست دارم به حقایق و جزئيات بپردازم',1:'خودم را آدم واقع 
بينی ميدانم',
        2:'ترجيح ميدهم در همين لحظه زندگی کنم',3:'من اهل عمل هستم',
        4:'دوست دارم محکم و با ایمان باشم',5:'من واقع بين و اهل عمل 
هستم',
        6:'ارزش هر چيز به اندازه قيمت آن در بازار است'}
question_N={0:'دوست دارم بدانم فراتر از سطح ظاهری رویدادها چه اتفاقی می 
افتد',
        1:'بعضی ها مرا یک آدم خيالباف تلقی می کنند',2:'من به نسبت دیگران 
خودم را آرمان گرا ميدانم',
        3:'تمایل به آینده نگری دارم',4:'به الهامات و حس درونی خودم اهميت 
زیادی می دهم',
        5:'به احساسم در مورد آینده اطمينان ميکنم',
        6:'ترجيح می دهم تصویری کلی از آنچه رخ می دهد داشته باشم'}
question_T={0:'ترجيح می دهم با هر چيزی به طور منطقی برخورد کنم',1:'من 
معقول و بی طرف هستم',
    2:'اغلب، بر پایه اصول و قواعد تصميم ميگيرم',
    3:'گاهی اوقات لازم است در برابر دیگران راسخ و محکم باشيم',4:'دوست 
دارم بفهمم چرا وقایع رخ می دهند',
    5:'عدالت مهم تر از محبت و دلسوزی است',6:'معتقدم که انسانها از مغزخود 
به حد کافی استفاده نمی کنند'}
question_F={0:'دوست دارم بيشتر به احساسم (ندای قلبم) توجه کنم تا عقلم',
        1:'در ارزیابی حرفها، بيشتر برایم مهم است که چه کسی این حرف را 
زده',
        2:'سياستهای تشویقی هميشه مؤثرتر از اجبار هستند',
    3:'تلاش می کنم بين مردم هماهنگی و توافق باشد',4:'من با دیگران مهربان 
هستم و با آنها اظهارهمدردی می کنم',
        5:'احساس را بر منطق ترجيح می دهم',6:'همدردی و بخشش والاترین 
ارزشهای من هستند'}
question_J={0:'دوست دارم مطابق برنامه ریزی عمل کنم',1:'دوست دارم با دقت 
برنامه ریزی کنم',
    2:'خودم را قاطع و مصمم ميدانم',
    3:'هميشه دقيق و وقت شناس هستم',4:'پایبند بودن به تکاليف و وظيفه ها 
برایم مهم است',
    5:'مرتب و با انضباط هستم',6:'دوست دارم همه چيزتحت کنترل من باشد'}
question_P={0:'تغيير و تحولات زیاد در زندگی را دوست دارم',1:'من کنجکاو 
هستم',
        2:'اتفاقات غيرمنتظره را دوست دارم',
    3:'از تازگی و تنوع لذت می برم',4:'زندگی را با آسودگی و بدون شتاب سپری 
می کنم',
        5:'بسيار انعطاف پذیر هستم',
    6:'برای ایجاد انگيزه در خودم، به دیگران نيازی ندارم'}
all_questions = {0 : question_E,1:question_S,2:question_T,3:question_J,
             4:question_I,5:question_N,6:question_F,7:question_P}
result_list = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
def start (bot,update):
    keyboard_list = [[InlineKeyboardButton("ABOUT US", callback_data='1')],
                    [InlineKeyboardButton("MBTI Test Start", 
    callback_data='2')]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard_list)
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    start_message_sent = "Welcome To My Bot Please Chose Your Options"
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id,start_message_sent, reply_markup=reply_markup)
def bottom(bot, update):
    query = update.callback_query
    chat_id = query.message.chat_id
    selected_option = int(query.data)
    if selected_option==1 :
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"You Chose About Us Section Thanks For 
Choosing Us")
    elif selected_option==2:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"You Are Ready To Start Test ...")

def Questions (bot,update,x,y):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    keyboard_list = [[InlineKeyboardButton(u"اصلا", callback_data='1')],
                 [InlineKeyboardButton(u"کمی", callback_data='2')],
                 [InlineKeyboardButton(u"متوسط", callback_data='3')],
                 [InlineKeyboardButton(u"زیاد", callback_data='4')],
                 [InlineKeyboardButton(u"خیلی زیاد", callback_data='5')]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard_list)
    start_message_sent = all_questions[x][y]
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, start_message_sent, reply_markup=reply_markup)
def answers (bot,update,x,y):
    query = update.callback_query
    chat_id = query.message.chat_id
    selected_option = int(query.data)
    result_list[x] += selected_option
handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(handler)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(bottom))
counter = 0


for i in range (0,8):
    for j in range (0,7):
        new_question = all_questions[i][j]
        counter +=1
        print ("Question number ",counter ,new_question)
        updater.dispatcher.add_handler(Handler(Questions))



updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: what is the reason to use uppercase every first letter?

Comment: @anatol just to be easy to read...

Comment: *just to be easy to read* - but it has inverted effect